# How to order an autonomous taxi in Dubai?

Tags: dubai, taxis

I read on the web that there is a Tesla fleet of 50 autonomous taxis in Dubai.

1. Does anyone know how to order one?
2. Where is the information about pricing?
3. Is Tesla the only provider of autonomous taxis in Dubai?

Comment: Why is this getting off-topic votes?  Taxis are a form of travel.

Comment: @gerrit The close votes are for it being a shopping question. I'm voting to leave open, but I'd say it's borderline: it asks where to find prices rather than what the prices are (good), but the third question is definitely the sort of thing that can go out of date (bad). BTW, you could go to the review queue and vote to leave open, too!

Comment: Meh. I think it's a good question for our times, but I also see where the *reasons* for prohibiting shopping questions do also apply to it.  5 years from now it will seem silly.

Comment: There are no autonomous taxis in Dubai. You can get a Tesla, but it comes with a driver. You can order them on Uber or you can get one at the airport.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you can [order a Dubai Taxi Corporation electric taxi via UberONE](http://www.timeoutdubai.com/travel/news/79323-uber-adds-electric-teslas-to-its-dubai-fleet), as of October 2017. There is also "[a new system](https://electrek.co/2017/09/18/tesla-vehicles-dubai-taxi-service/)" for ordering at the airport, but it's unclear how that works or if you can specifically request a Tesla.

Currently, they will not be "autonomous taxis" in that there will be a driver. There has to be, under current Dubai law. [It may run the Autopilot software](http://www.arabianbusiness.com/content/376007-will-tesla-cars-in-dubai-be-on-autopilot-by-year-end) which provides assistance to the driver and they apparently have all the hardware required to become autonomous given updates in the software and the law, but not quite yet.

Regarding the price, [this news site](https://www.khaleejtimes.com/news/transport/can-you-afford-an-uber-tesla-in-uae-yes-is-the-answer) says the price via UberONE will be the same as UberBLACK, specifically: Dh10 base fare, plus Dh0.80 per minute, Dh1.90 per km, and a minimum total fare of Dh20.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie whoops, head in the wrong country there ;)

Comment: UberONE drivers are NOT allowed use Tesla Autopilot software. I've been told that by multiple UberONE drivers.